# Can't apply theme colors from Chakra to React Icons

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I have a react application with the UI made with Chakra UI and with some React Icons as well.

In my `theme.ts` file for Chakra I extended the base theme with some more colors:

```
export const theme = extendTheme({
  colors: {
    main: {
      black: '#1C1A1B',
      blackOffset: '#252525',
      white: '#FFFFFF',
      whiteOffset: '#f0f0f0',
      orange: '#D55C31',
    },
...
```

In the application I can use those colors in the following way:

```
              <Text color="main.white">white text</Text>
              <Text color="main.black">black text</Text>
```

And it works, the color assigned is exactly the color that I specify in the `theme.ts` file.

The problem is that the same principle doesn't work for React Icons, so when I have something like this:

```
     import { FaDiscord, FaTwitter } from 'react-icons/fa';

...

              <FaDiscord
                aria-label="Discord Contact"
                // color={colorMode === 'dark' ? 'main.white' : 'main.black'}
                color="main.white"
                size={20}
              />
```

The icon color is the default one, not white.
The icon's color is correct if I use just `white` or `black` instead of `main.white` or `main.black`...

What am I missing?

Comment: You'll want to use the Icon component. Chakra includes a react-icons example in their docs: https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/media-and-icons/icon#using-a-third-party-icon-library